# How to get data from Perl data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures

I've parsed JSON into the following data structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '041012020' => {
                            'item_number' => 'P2345'
                          },
          '041012021' => {
                            'item_number' => 'I0965'
                          },
          '041012022' => {
                            'item_number' => 'R2204'
                          }
        };
```

I'm trying to get the values of item_numbers using the following code, and it's giving me the HASH Values as output rather than the actual item_number values. Please guide me to get the expected values.

```perl
foreach my $value (values %{$json_obj}) {
       say "Value is: $value,";
 }
```

Output:

```
Value is: HASH(0x557ce4e2f3c0),
Value is: HASH(0x557ce4e4de18),
Value is: HASH(0x557ce4e4dcf8),
```

If I use the same code to get the keys it's working perfectly fine

```perl
foreach my $key (keys %{$json_obj}) {
        say "Key is: $key,";
 }
```

Output:

```
Key is: 041012020,
Key is: 041012020,
Key is: 041012022,
```

Comment: Your input is a Perl hash value. There is no JSON in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of the hash elements are references to hashes (`{ item_number => 'P2345' }`). That's what you get when you stringify a reference. If you want the item number, you'll need to tell Perl that.

```perl
for my $value (values %$data) {
   say $value->{item_number};
}
```

or

```perl
for my $item_number ( map { $_->{item_number} } values %$data ) {
   say $item_number;
}
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response, when I use both of above snippets I'm getting `Use of uninitialized value in say at test.pl line 41. and Use of uninitialized value $item_number in say at test.pl line 45.

Comment: I changed misnamed `$json_obj` (which isn't JSON) to `$data`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Thanks @Ikegami it's working as expected, I appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks, I thought to vote it so I did but checked the mark too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short code for your question.

```
    #!usr/bin/perl
    
    $VAR1 = {
              '041012020' => {
                                'item_number' => 'P2345'
                              },
              '041012021' => {
                                'item_number' => 'I0965'
                              },
              '041012022' => {
                                'item_number' => 'R2204'
                              }
            };
            
    print "$VAR1->{$_}->{item_number}\n" for keys %$VAR1;
```

To use for in a block:

```
for my $key (keys %$VAR1) {
    print "$VAR1->{$key}->{item_number}\n"
}
```